# C++ importing and using ADO

Tags: c++, ado

I have two short questions involving importing and using ADO in a C++ project. I am not experienced with ADO in any form.

First, for the time being the database aspect of my program need only run on Windows. Is it enough to test if _WIN32 or _WIN64 is defined before running ADO specific code, or are there better approaches? I am using Visual C++ 2010 Express as my compiler.

Second, I am following [this page](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/intro_to_ado_in_c++.html) as my guide. I've included the #import statement for msado15.dll. The #import directive is underlined red, and the error I receive when hovering over it says "...cannot open source file path/to/msado15.tlh," and any ADO stuff I copy into the source stays red underlined. I've checked the directory listed in the error message and msado15.tlh is there, if that matters. Also, the program compiles (it crashes though after executing, but that's something else I'll diagnose separately).

I'm pretty clueless about why this is happening. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your machine 32bit or 64bit? If 64bit, you need to point to Program Files (x86)

Comment: Please refer the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42036189/msado15-tlh-not-generated-after-importing-msado15-dll/46540869#46540869

Comment: Please refer the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42036189/msado15-tlh-not-generated-after-importing-msado15-dll/46540869#46540869

Answer (score 10):

The way we do it, we add the following to out VC++ Directories / Include files

```
$(ProgramFiles)\Common Files\System\ado
```

And then we import like this

in the header:

```
#import "msado15.dll" rename_namespace("ADO") rename("EOF", "EndOfFile") no_implementation
```

At the top of the cpp file

```
#import "msado15.dll" rename_namespace("ADO") rename("EOF", "EndOfFile") implementation_only
```

A little different, since we prefer to keep the namespace, and use a different EOF rename.

[C++ Import help on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

[C++ Import Attributes on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/298h7faa.aspx)

Comment: I never knew about `no_implementation` and `implementation_only`. I think that's a very nice way of handling it, making header files much lighter rather than dragging along the full implementation of ADO when they're included.

Comment: I am having a similar problem, I have tried all these fixes and it is not working. But I agree that these solutions should work on a new project. I am just guessing that VS 2010 has a bit of a trouble with msado15.dll. I converted a project from VS 2003 to 2010 and whenever I try to compile it the tbl file generated has a bug related to the EOF symbol. Apparently the compiler does not buy the rename macro substitution. I have a topic here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715900/converting-application-from-visual-studio-2003-to-visual-studio-2010-ado-c. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this works? devenv.exe is a 32 bit app, therefore $(Program Files) environment variable always points to the 32 bit folder.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. It worked then, it works now. $(ProgramFiles) resolves to "C:\Program Files (x86)" on my 64-bit Windows. To verify, go to project properties, general, and edit output directory. Click on the "Macros>>" button and see for yourself.

Comment: Thanks, that was so useful.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I started with ADO. (red underlined, can't find...)
It drove me nuts but after simply compiling, the underline went away and everything worked fine.

I use 
   `#import "C:\Program\Delade filer\System\ado\msado15.dll" rename_namespace("USEADO"),rename("EOF","EndOfFile")` 
in my header.

In cpp eg:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int SQLsetInfo(THING *Thing, GADGET *Gadget)
{

HRESULT hr;                                                         
USEADO::_ConnectionPtr connection;                                  
USEADO::_RecordsetPtr recordset;                                    

 //Initialize COM  
    if(FAILED(hr = CoInitialize(NULL)))                         
    {   MessageBox( NULL, L"Initialize COM Failed", L"MyProg!",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION |MB_OK);
        //Do something, eg shut down DB stuff and continue without or exit program
        //Insert error handeler below
        return hr;//TODO Ad error handeling see line 149
    }   

if(FAILED(hr = connection.CreateInstance(__uuidof(USEADO::Connection))))
    {   MessageBox( NULL, L"Create connection instance Failed", L"MyProg!",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION |MB_OK);
        //Do something, eg shut down DB stuff and continue without or exit program
        return hr;
    }

if(FAILED(hr = recordset.CreateInstance(__uuidof(USEADO::Recordset))))
    {   MessageBox( NULL, L"Create recordset instance Failed", L"MyProg!",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION |MB_OK);
        //Do something, eg shut down DB stuff and continue without or exit program 
        return hr;
    }

    connection->CursorLocation = USEADO::adUseServer; //http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/vb-cursors-and-locks.html                                           

    //Try to connect to SQL server
    try         { connection->Open(L"YOUR CONNECTION STRING", USEADO::adConnectUnspecified);    }
    catch(...)  {std::cout << "!!! connection->Open(ConnectionString   FAILED !!!" << std::endl;        }
```

I'm **not** an expert in C++, but this works fine for me. Hope it helps you to. If anyone else here has suggestions/critic to the above snippet I'm looking forward to it....