# msado15.tlh not generated after importing msado15.dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to use [/MP (Build with Multiple Processes)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385193.aspx) option to enable multi-process compilation, however, it conflicts with #import, so I'm trying the workaround proposed in [Replacement for #import in Visual C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650578/replacement-for-import-in-visual-c) :

For anyone else stumbling over this in google:

1. create a separate static lib project
2. set up enough includes so you can put the #import statement in the lib project
3. make your main project dependent on the lib project (to ensure correct build order)
4. add the lib project's temporary build folder to the include path for
   the main project
5. `#include` the generated .tlh files where you were doing the #import
6. enable the /MP switch and lose the coffee break time...

I foolowed the steps, however, "msado15.tlh" was not generated.

Here's what I do:

1. create a static library project `AdoImport`
2. Add a header file `AddImport.h` in the `AdoImport` project, contains only one line: `#import "C:/Program Files/Common Files/System/ado/msado15.dll"  rename("EOF", "adoEOF") rename("BOF", "adoBOF")`
3. compile

I'm expecting a `msado15.tlh` will be generated in `AdoImport` proejct's `Debug` folder, but it's not found. The compilation reports success and only generated `AdoImport.lib`.

How shall I make `msado15.tlh` generated so my main project could include it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just in case anyone hit this by google, how i solved it --

put the line `#import "C:/Program Files/Common Files/System/ado/msado15.dll"  rename("EOF", "adoEOF") rename("BOF", "adoBOF")` in the `stdafx.h` of the `AdoImport` project so that it alway get compiled.

`AdoImport` project's "intermediate Directory" (under Project Property -> Configuration Properties -> General) shall be included in the main project's paths.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for providing the solution. Going by this I tried to create the same in VS2015, but somehow not worked.

So I added the import statement

#import "C:/Program Files/Common Files/System/ado/msado15.dll"  rename("EOF", "adoEOF") rename("BOF", "adoBOF")

in my Main Project's Precompiled Header File StdAfx.h and compiled the StdAfx.cpp and soon after that the #import error stating "..cannot open msado15.tlh" is resolved. This is simple work around without any need to create the Library. But you answer led me to resolve this. Thanks to you.

Thanks,
Kamleshwar.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same error message in VS2019, but for a different reason.  The destination folder for the .tlh file was read-only.  I unchecked read-only on the folder.  VS created the tlh and the error message disappeared.